# How to make auto suggestion in mean stack

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I have this code :

```
async function getUserByArtistName(artistName) {
  let userDB = await User.find(
      {$text: { $search: artistName}},
      (err, res) => {
        if(err){
          console.log("ERROR : ")
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          console.log(res)
        }
      });
  return userDB;
}
```

and i need to find user where User.artistName contains * artistName *. is it possible ?

Thank you verry much !

Comment: `$text` requires a text index, so it will search the fields that you specified when creating the index.

Comment: i have created the index on my  schema

Answer (score 0):

the answer :

```
async function getUserByArtistName(artistName) {
  let userDB = await User.find(
      { artistName: { $regex: artistName, $options: "i" } },
      (err, res) => {
        if(err){
          console.log("ERROR : ")
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          console.log(res)
        }
      });
  return userDB;
}
```